# MongoDB java driver get records where date between and user is

Tags: java, mongodb, date, nosql

From a collection named **"persons"**, I want to retreive all records **where date is between**

```
"14-11-2014" and "20-11-2014"  <-- These are both in string format (dd-mm-yyyy)
```

AND

```
user: "Erik"
```

**My mongoDB**

```
{
  "_id" : "546c9f26dbeaa7186ab042c4",          <------this one should NOT be retreived
  "Task: "Sometask"                                                because of the user
  "date" : "20-11-2014",
  "user" : "Dean"
},
{
  "_id" : "546caef6dbeaa7186ab042c5",          <--------- This one should be retreived
  "task": "A task",
  "date" : "20-11-2014",
  "user" : "Erik"
}
{
  "_id" : "546caef6dbeaa7186ab042c5",          <----- This one should NOT be retreived
  "task": "A task",                                         because of the date
  "date" : "13-11-2014",
  "user" : "Erik"
}
```

I am using java mongo java driver 2.11.3

Maybe there is some solution using BasicDBObject?

I'm very curious.. thanks

**EDIT**

I'm using:

```
public static String findTimelines(String begin, String end, String username) throws UnknownHostException, JSONException{
    DBCollection dbCollection = checkConnection("timelines");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("date", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", begin).add("$lte",end).get());
    query.put("user", username);
    dbCollection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("date", -1));
    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
    return JSON.serialize(cursor);
}
```

Does work until you query something like "28-11-2014" to "01-12-2014", It doesn't return anything even though there is a object with date: "30-11-2014". I think this is because of the month change.
**Also** that object is retreived when you do: "28-11-2014" to "30-11-2014" because of the month staying the same

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like  this

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("date", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromDate).add("$lte", toDate).get());
collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("date", -1));
```

Comment: Really good! The dates part work.. It indeed filters the correct records.. But now with the username incorporated in your answer please. If you add the username part and it works.. I'll select it as the answer :D

Comment: Nevermind, I improved your answer by putting query.put("user", user); after the first query.put(foo)

Comment: Ok great i appreciate your effort!

Comment: Hey Ramzan! This answer has worked for me for the pas few days, but now it needs to get dates between say: "28-11-2014" and "02-12-2014". The query doesn't work anymore now. Because of the monthchange? Do you know what to do to improve this?

Comment: There is noting wrong with the query! Can you post your code?

Comment: The query might work in some cases, but since strings will be lexically compared, it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you would use:

```
db.posts.find({date: {$gte: start, $lt: end}, user: 'Erik'});
```

You should first parse your date using `SimpleDateFormat` or alike to get a `Date` object.

Then put together your query using `BasicDBObject`:

```
BasicDBObject q = new BasicDBObject();
q.append("date", new BasicDBObject().append("$gte", start).append("$lt", end));
q.append("user", "Erik");

collection.find(q);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Even though your answer works, the answer from Ramzan Zafar works without converting the string and therefore is a slightly bit cleaner. It's a shame I can't select you both as the right answer.. a +1 though for fast reply and correct answer